# Can I make Qt Quick use compressed textures?

Tags: qt, compression, qml, textures, qt-quick

My Qt Quick app is using too much memory. Can I make it use compressed textures for everything, to mitigate that?

Comment: You may try to set the [`sourceSize`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#sourceSize-prop) to load your images in a smaller size. There is also this mysterious sentence *For some formats (currently only JPEG), the whole image will never actually be loaded into memory.* which might hint, how memory might be saved. I have not tried that yet.

Comment: What memory, ram, vram?

Answer (score -1):

Compressed textures only affects the resource size (executable size also), they need to be decompressed at runtime which needs the memory for decompressed one and in some cases compressed one too, therefore compressing textures won't help you as it should.

However if you have images used as icons, consider converting them font characters and use them with text or label elements, this helped me to reduce memory usage from 250Mb to around 100Mb (using around 100 icons)